# Why does OS X need permission to allow JLink connections each time it starts?

Tags: mac-os-x, java, system-limitations

I understand that [JLink loads each time](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/665/37) *Mathematica* launches or each time a kernel starts, and that this can require permission from the firewall, if it is enabled

[image]

but OS X provides settings the provide this permission by default, so that I don't have to provide it each time *Mathematica* starts (a process that seems to cause delays and even crashes *Mathematica* in some cases).  However, even if I give this permission, I still get asked for it again, each time.

[image]

*Mathematica* is is the only application on my system that does this. Why? Is there some way to configure *Mathematica* so that it behaves as it should; or is this a bug? What does *Mathematica* need "incoming network connections" for anyway? Can turn off the need for them in *Mathematica*  somewhere?

Comment: Related or possibly duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/any-way-to-prevent-mac-firewall-from-asking-to-allow-connections-all-the-time

Comment: @cormullion: Very drastic solutions. I wonder if there are others (e.g., within *Mathematica* disabling whatever is requiring incoming connections in the first place).

Comment: You can block all access to the internet from within mma by setting `$AllowInternet` (or ``PacletManager`$AllowInternet`` if not loaded) to `False`. However, you won't be able to use the curated data, W|A, free form input, etc.

Comment: @rm-rf: What about just *incoming* connections?

Comment: *Mathematica* is made up of several MathLink programs: the kernel, the front end, J/Link, the subkernels, whatever else you install... and clearly for each outgoing connection the partner program needs to accept an incoming one. As to what these messages mean and how to stop them, I don't know... I don't use a Mac. However, you should definitely check what subnets you are allowing connections from. Letting anyone on the Internet connect to you would not be a good idea.

Comment: Just for reference, the same has cropped up on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/AfsQ0ck0cjQ/discussion), but nobody seems to know a solution. I also see this problem, but only on a desktop Mac at the office, not on my laptop. I included this link because in the future an answer may appear there...

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I don't think it's a question of actually making connections. I just checked and no component of mathematica accepted connections from outside (in 20-30min of logging); things like searching in help do connecto to wolfram servers, but it's an outgoing connection. In short, I think it's an artifact of how the OS X application firewall does things (perhaps only for "unsigned" applications but I do not know much about that).

Comment: @Jens I see the problem on my MacBook Pro, but not on my iMac at work. Both run the same version of OSX and the same version of Mma.